# 'ChartsModule' does not appear to be an NgModule, Component, Directive, or Pipe class

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, angular16

I have installed chart.js and ng2charts, the version details are below:

```
 "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
 "chartjs-gauge": "^0.3.0",
 "ng2-charts": "^2.4.3"
```

On import it's showing the error:
**'ChartsModule' does not appear to be an NgModule, Component, Directive, or Pipe class.(-996003)
charts.module.d.ts(1, 22): This likely means that the library (ng2-charts) which declares ChartsModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.**

And when I replace "ChartsModule" with "NgChartsModule", It's showing the below error :

**'"ng2-charts"' has no exported member named 'NgChartsModule'. Did you mean 'ChartsModule'?**

- Note : Before Angular upgrade, I was using 'NgChartsModule'. And it was working fine.

I upgrade my angular version from 11 to 16 and after that chart library is not working. I have tried  with newer/latest version of both the libraries but that too did not work.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure that you are installing ng2-charts v5.x as you are using Angular 16. https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts?tab=readme-ov-file#angular-version-compability-table